# KSOAP2 Marshal Array of Complex Objects

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I would like to send an array of complex objects as a parameter to a .NET web service.  The class I have is ksoap2 serializable.  After I make the call, the SoapRequest property shows my array as AnyType.  This gives a casting error because the server does not know how to convert it.

**Theory:**
I feel that the issue can be solved with Marshalling.  I have seen the examples on See Sharp Geers, but those are for primitive types.  How do you do an array and include the type in the WriteInstance method?

Can anyone provide sample code for marshalling an array of complex objects?

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Comment: did you got any idea ? any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to the ksoap2 google group: [How to send a Complext type Array](http://groups.google.com/group/ksoap2-android/browse_thread/thread/f8e17bdecc6b65d7#)  which describes how to send an array of complex type. Maybe this will help you. Found it while searching for a way to send one complex object to a wcf service. But i don't get it working :/ If you have any idea, check my question ;)

[kSoap2 serialisation error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6326035/795051)

Comment: I would really like to know how to marshal a complex array - code that will build the SOAP using the array type and the type of the object etc.  I just don't know the rules for the write override and was hoping that someone did this before.  Thanks!